# MySQL left join with default values

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a couple of tables, one with source data which I'll call `SourceData` and another which defines overridden values for a given user if they exist called `OverriddenSourceData`.

The basic table format looks something this like:

```
SourceData
| source_id |  payload         |
--------------------------------
| 1         |  'some json'     |
| 2         | 'some more json' |
--------------------------------


OverriddenSourceData
| id |  source_id | user_id | overrides 
| 1  |    2       |  4      |  'a change'     |
------------------------------------------
```

For a given user, I'd like to return all the Source data rows with the `overrides` column included.  If the user has overridden the source then the column is populated, else it is null.

I started by executing a left join and then including a condition for checking the user like so:

```
SELECT A.source_id, A.payload, B.overrides from SourceData A
LEFT JOIN OverriddenSourceData B
ON A.source_id = B.source_id
WHERE user_id = 4
```

but then source rows that weren't overridden wouldn't be included ( it was acting like an inner join) (e.g source id 1)

I then relaxed the query and used a strict left join on `source_id`.

```
SELECT A.source_id, A.payload, B.overrides from SourceData A
LEFT JOIN OverriddenSourceData B
ON A.source_id = B.source_id
# WHERE user_id = 4
```

This can return more data than I need though (e.g other users who have overridden the same source data) and then I have to filter programatically.

It seems like I should be able to craft a query that does this all the DB level and gives me what I need. Any help?

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your condition on `LEFT JOIN` clause, if you use `WHERE`, mysql will do it with `INNER JOIN`, so try this;)

```
SELECT A.source_id, A.payload, B.overrides from SourceData A
LEFT JOIN OverriddenSourceData B
ON A.source_id = B.source_id
AND B.user_id = 4
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Much appreciated!